# How to use Interval in countDownTimer in Android

Tags: android, android-timer

In my application i should use **CountDownTimer** and for this I want use this library : [CountdownView](https://github.com/iwgang/CountdownView).
I want when lasted 5s show me `Toast`.
For example : I want show 17s **countTimer**, when this timer receive to 5s show me `toast` "just 5s".
I use this code, but show me ever 5s .

```
long time1 = 17 * 1000;
mCvCountdownViewTest1.start(time1);
mCvCountdownViewTest1.setOnCountdownIntervalListener(5000, new CountdownView.OnCountdownIntervalListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInterval(CountdownView cv, long remainTime) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Just 5s ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I want just lasted 5s not ever 5s.

how can i it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By modifying your code:

```
boolean toastShown = false;
long time1 = 17 * 1000;
mCvCountdownViewTest1.start(time1);
mCvCountdownViewTest1.setOnCountdownIntervalListener(1000, new CountdownView.OnCountdownIntervalListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInterval(CountdownView cv, long remainTime) {
        if(remainTime < 5000 && !toastShown) {
            toastShown = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Just 5s ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

You can try this code also:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(17000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "running" + millisUntilFinished, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (millisUntilFinished < 5000) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "5 sec left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Countdown Timer Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: I should use above library, can you help me with my above library? please my friend

Comment: Thanks my dear friend, your help is very wonderful for me. thanks my friend, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check how many seconds remains.
I rewrote your code:

```
long time1 = 17L * 1000;
mCvCountdownViewTest1.start(time1);
mCvCountdownViewTest1.setOnCountdownIntervalListener(1000, new CountdownView.OnCountdownIntervalListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInterval(CountdownView cv, long remainTime) {
        long remainTimeInSeconds = remainTime / 1000;
        if (remainTimeInSeconds  == 5) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Just 5s ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your help, but not work and not show me any toast! please help me my friend, I really need this help :( :(

Comment: @OoO3 I edited code from answer, check it, now may work